# How can I get role before render()

Tags: reactjs

I want to do the following:

- send a request to the server, verify JSON web-token and get user details (name, email and role);
- then the page appears with the specific menu items (if the user is admin it shows him Main, Admin and Logout items; if not - Main and Logout).

I thought about just getting the token from localStorage, then decoding it and taking a role from it. But what should I do if I change the role in database (for example from admin to user)? Decoded token on the client-side will contain the "admin" role. So this user will be able to see the admin page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow friend. Could you please answer in which platform or framework are you working? E.x. React.js, Python, Java?

Comment: @marcode_ely Tag is saying *React.js* ..

Comment: You need to handle authorization in the backend code too, so that you can defeat the problems you explained in the post.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking about the mechanism for the initial display, or the problem of synchronizing the local-stored token state to the server state (which may have changed in the meantime). You may want to consider editing to refocus the question. If the question is about synchronizing state, you may want to more research. That question in isolation may already have answers.

Comment: In short I want to get a user's role everytime he enters a specific page, but I can't do this because the page renders before `fetch().then(...)` gets a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable in store called `isFetchingUserDetails` and set it to true when you make that async call to the server to get the details.

Till `isFetchingUserDetails` is set true, you can have an if statement in the render() to return a spinner or other component which shows the user that the page is loading.

Once you get the response from the server, `isFetchingUserDetails` will be set to false and the rest of the render() will be executed.

*Without Store*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isFetchingUserDetails: true };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.makethecall.com/users/1`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(() => this.setState({ isFetchingUserDetails: false }));
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.isFetchingUserDetails) {
        return <Spinner />
    }
    return (
      <Home />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean localStorage?

Comment: I meant a global store like redux. But if you are not using one, you can use state variable as I have shown in my answer.